# How to make android app as the default launcher on a tablet

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, android-launcher, kiosk-mode

I am working on a kiosk mode application,wherein I want my app to work as the default launcher,instead of the android launcher.On device reboot my app should pop up as the default launcher.For the same,I have created an app to act as a launcher for a kiosk mode application running on an android tablet namely iBall 3G7171 HD7(4.2.2).In the manifest I have given the relevant permissions as follows.

```
<activity
    android:name="com.abc.Main"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:launchMode="singleTop"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <!-- The following two intent-filters are the key to set homescreen -->
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />                 
    </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

While I run this code on my samsung s2, on reboot this app is launched as the launcher app and works as expected.**However,when I run it on my tablet** I see that the app is not launched as the launcher app on device reboot,instead its the default android launcher that pops up.

**What I tried :** I listened to the BOOT COMPLETE intent to launch my launcher app.But the problem here is that the BOOT COMPLETE intent is fired after about 5 seconds,during which the default android launcher shows up,post which my launcher app is called.I do not want it to work this way,hence the approach of listening to boot complete broadcast won't work for my case.

**What I want** : Is to launch my launcher app immediately when my device reboots.
What is it that I am missing/doing wrong in my current code.Any help would be appreciated.Many thanks !

Comment: You should focus on discovering why setting your app is the launcher is not working on the table - the boot receiver is likely not your path to a solution, or at least not the primary part of the solution.

Comment: @ChrisStratton : Yes,I have ruled out using boot complete as the solution due to its inherent delay.I browsed a lot of suggestions for my issue, most of all point to using the code shown above in the manifest,but in vain for me :/

Comment: As a check you could try the sample "Home" project from the legacy folder of the SDK samples package.  But it may be that what you face is a (vendor introduced?) oddity on this tablet.

Comment: @ChrisStratton : It may be vendor introduced,though I am not sure.I need to research more to conclude this.Thanks for your suggestions mate.

Comment: @ChrisStratton : I went through the "Home" project.They too are using the same intents like me.Suppose if its a vendor introduced,then is removing the default android launcher app the only solution(Will this cause any other issues)?

Comment: Can you actually remove it?  I'd assume the default is a factory app.

Comment: @ChrisStratton : Some links I read say that we can remove the default launcher on rooted devices.(http://www.droidforums.net/forum/bugless/45360-remove-default-launcher.html)

Comment: If that doesn't work maybe installing a new ROM would.

Comment: Hello, Have you solved this issue?

Answer (score 2):

If you are ok using adb shell command, then

1. Install your current app in device.
2. Connect to pc/mac enable usb debugging. Find the package name of your default launcher using this
   command. "**adb shell pm list packages**"
3. Disable the default launcher 
   "**adb shell pm hide com.android.yourlauncher**"

done.